# document.querySelector not selecting class

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to get this to work

`app.js`:

```js
    const api = 'xxxxxxxx';

    function ySearch(e) {
    const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/? 
    part=snippet&key='+api+'&q=test&maxResults=20';

    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = url;
 
    }
```

`html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text">
        <button>Search</button>
        <div class="output"></div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Expected: When I reload the `html`, I get to see the `url` value.
But the output class `div` is not being populated for some reason. What could be going wrong?

Comment: As first step, put your script in the `<head>`, and add the `async` and `defer` attributes, so that your script loads without blocking the page, and automatically runs only after the DOM has been parsed.

Comment: You don't appear to call the function `ySearch()` anywhere

Comment: You can use the `<output>` tag instead of `div.output`. Have a look at the `load` & `DOMContentLoaded` events, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event. You need to wait for the elements to be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ySearch` for it to run, so you need an event listener on the button, to handle the click:

```js
function ySearch(e) {
    const url = 'https://...';
    document.querySelector('.output').textContent = url;
}

// add event listener to button 
document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', ySearch)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="app.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text">
  <button id="searchButton" >Search</button>
  <div class="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not 1998 anymore though: this should use `addEventListener` on the JS side, not be an HTML4 onclick attribute.

Comment: You are correct, I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't calling the function:

```js
const api = 'xxxxxxxx';

function ySearch(e) {
  const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&key=' + api + '&q=test&maxResults=20';

  document.querySelector('.output').textContent = url;

}

const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', ySearch)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text">
  <button>Search</button>
  <div class="output"></div>
</body>

</html>
```